# Как получить несколько значений из useQuery GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Я делаю интернет-магазин и хочу подсчитать суммарную стоимость продуктов в ней. Корзина выглядит так: [{productId, count}, {productId, count}], а стоимость продукта я получаю через запрос по productId.

Ниже пример того, как выглядит идеальная структура, которую я хотел бы получить, но useQuery нельзя использовать внутри map и useQuery является асинхронным. Уже по-разному пробовал решить это, но так ни к чему и не пришёл.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту задачу или может есть другой способ?

```
import {useQuery, useMutation} from "@apollo/client";
import {GET_PRODUCT_PRICE} from "../query/product";

export const GetTotalPrice = (cart) => {
    let totalPrice = 0;
    const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(GET_PRODUCT_PRICE, {
        variables: {
            id: productId
        }
    });
    
    cart.map((product) => {
        const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(GET_PRODUCT_PRICE, {
            variables: {
                id: product.productId
            }
        });

        totalPrice += data.getProduct.price * product.count;
    })

    return totalPrice;
}
```